# Chain dispatch actions in row

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have to chain two actions in a row in a Redux Tookit, however so far i have managed to do it only in parallel. Below is the snippet i am trying to refractor. How to force the second action to start after competion of first action?

```
const onSubmit = async () => {
    await Promise.all([
      dispatch(action1({})),<-- wait before second action starts.
      dispatch(action2({}))
    ]);
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `createAsyncThunk` returns a standard Redux thunk action creator. And RTK adds `redux-thunk` as its default middleware. You can use [Composition](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#composition) feature of `redux-thunk`. So that you can dispatch the thunk action creator serially based on JS promise chain call feature

> Any return value from the inner function will be available as the return value of dispatch itself. This is convenient for orchestrating an asynchronous control flow with thunk action creators dispatching each other and returning Promises to wait for each other’s completion

E.g.

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const api = () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

const action1 = createAsyncThunk('app/action1', async () => {
  await api();
  return 'action1 response';
});

const action2 = createAsyncThunk('app/action2', async () => {
  return 'action2 response';
});

const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'app',
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(action1.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      return state;
    });
  },
});

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    users: usersSlice.reducer,
  },
});

store
  .dispatch(action1())
  .then((res1) => {
    console.log(res1);
    return store.dispatch(action2());
  })
  .then((res2) => console.log(res2));
```

Output:

```
{
  type: 'app/action1/fulfilled',
  payload: 'action1 response',
  meta: {
    arg: undefined,
    requestId: 'vQo835AGEI755Po5xWcER',
    requestStatus: 'fulfilled'
  }
}
{
  type: 'app/action2/fulfilled',
  payload: 'action2 response',
  meta: {
    arg: undefined,
    requestId: 'KJmLsXzZCLxx2BslvkfNu',
    requestStatus: 'fulfilled'
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry for beginner question but I have tried to chain the dispatch code however i have got an error: 'then' does not exist on type 'AsyncThunkAction'. Where do I initiate the dispatch(action1()).then code?